# Meteor collection - count same values

Tags: mongodb, collections, meteor, spacebars

I need to count all products in descending order and display them with spacebars. How would I do that?
Result should be:
book : 2
tv   : 1

```
// My Collection
Records = new Mongo.Collection('records');


// My database
Records.insert({
    name: "a", product: "book"
});
Records.insert({
    name: "b", product: "tv"
});
Records.insert({
    name: "c", product: "book"
});


// My Template Helper - This sorts for alphatical order
Template.foo.helpers({
'counterRecords': function(){
    return Records.find({}, {sort: {product: 1}});
}});

// My Template
{{#each counterRecords}}
 {{counterRecords}}: {{counterRecords.count}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: use aggregation framework and groupby to count data by group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```js
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  counterRecords: function() {
    var records = Records.find().fetch();
    return _.chain(records).pluck('product')
      .countBy()
      .map(function(v, k) {return {product: k, count: v};})
      .sortBy('product')
      .value();
  }
});
```

That should produce an array like:

```js
[{product: 'book', count: 2}, {product: 'tv', count: 1}]
```

And your template could look something like this:

```html
{{#each counterRecords}}
 {{product}}: {{count}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: After the call to `map` you can add a `sortBy`, for example `.sortby('product')` would sort them alphabetically.

Comment: Sure - see the updated version. If you need it sorted some other way, let me know.

Comment: In that case it's easier to just reverse it at the end. i.e. replace `.value()` with `.value().reverse()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query :

```
Records.aggregate(
[
 {
    "$group" : {
        "_id" : "$product",
        "count" : {
            "$sum" : 1
        }
    }
 },
 {
     $sort:
      {
        _id:1
      }

 }
])
```